# Windows app to allow positioning windows in specific formations

Tags: gratis, windows-7, productivity, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop-environment

Can anyone recommend a gratis Windows 7 app that allows the user to reposition windows in specific useful formations?

Specifically:

- Positioning two windows side by side horizontally
  (the equivalent of: *select window A, press Win+LeftArrow, select window B, press Win+RightArrow* **or** *right-clicking on the Windows taskbar and selecting `Show windows side by side`*)
- Positioning two Windows next to each other vertically (no easy way to do that in Windows 7)

Other useful window layouts are a bonus, as well as recommendations for portable (no installer) apps.

Ideally, the app will have a quick way to access this functionality:  preferably global shortcut keys or an icon to the left of the *Minimize, Restore, Close* buttons in the upper-right corner of every window.

Comment: you can script it yourself with AutoHotkey or alternatives to that.